# Confusion Big O notation -

Tags: analysis, algorithms, asymptotics, self-learning

**Question : Is this what this property of Big O Notation is trying to explain?**

The Big O property , at the reference, it's the theorem 4,

**It says :**

*Let $d,e,f,g : N \to R $  be functions. Then :*

(4) $d(n) \in O(f(n))$ and $f(n) \in O(g(n)) $ then $d(n) \in O(g(n))$

**My understanding :**

$n^2 \in O(n^2) $ and $n^2 \in O(n^2) $ then $n^2 \in O(n^2)$

This seems correct but im not sure the theorem would be that simple.
I feel im missing something.. Would someone ,please, clarify?

**Reference :** `http://www.inf.ed.ac.uk/teaching/courses/cs2/LectureNotes/CS2Bh/ADS/02-03/lecture2.pdf`

Comment: Not sure i get it, i know that notation  : F(n) <= c * G(N)

Comment: My comments are now summarized in @dsaxton's answer so I'll remove them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another way to say this:

$d(n) \in O(f(n))$
means there is a
$u > 0$
such that,
for all large enough $n$,
$|d(n)| \le u|f(n)|$.

Similarly,
$f(n) \in O(g(n))$
means there is a
$v > 0$
such that,
for all large enough $n$,
$|f(n)| \le v|g(n)|$.

Therefore,
for all large enough $n$,
$|d(n)| \le u|f(n)|
\le uv|g(n)|$,
so that
$d(n) \in O(g(n))$,
with a valid value
for the constant being
$uv$.

Comment: Im trying to understand these statements.. If you have time would you confirm what you said with an example? Im doing my own by changing the functions but i wont be sure again that "im" correct.

Comment: Use $\le$ rather than $<$ to include cases when some $f(n)$ are zero (for example $\sin(n\pi/3)\in O(\sin(n\pi/6))$ although there is no positive $u$ such that $|\sin(n\pi/3)|<u\cdot|\sin(n\pi/6)|$ for every $n$ large enough).

Comment: Good point. Thanks. Fixed. Upvoted.

Answer (score 1):

It's more like a transitivity property of the big-O notation. A more suited example would be: $n \in O(n^2)$ and $n^2 \in O(n^3)$ so $n \in O(n^3)$.

Edit: you can also consider this example : $3n^2 + 3n \in O(n^2)$ and $n^2 \in O(n^3)$, so $3n^2 + 3n \in O(n^3)$

Comment: Wait, so you are saying that i could say that $O(1)$ $ \in $ $O(n^2) $?

Comment: Yes, but since $O(1)$ is a *set* of functions, more accurately you should say  $O(1) \subset O(n^2)$.

Answer (score 0):

If $|d(n) / f(n)|$ remains bounded as $n \to \infty$ and so does $|f(n) / g(n)|$, then what can we say about $|d(n) / g(n)| = |d(n) / f(n)| \cdot |f(n) / g(n)|$?

Comment: It should still remain bounded. Because we are multiplying two bounded functions?  Also, with g(n) , it means the O notation right? And d(n) and f(n) are other functions ? or f(n) refers to the O notation?